# Convert raw RGBA to UIImage

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimage

Yes, I know this sounds like a duplicate... but I've tried lots of examples and even Apple's official code on their developer page and this is resulting in a white image on iPhone 4S & iPad 3.
Works great on iPad 1 and the iPhone Simulator though.

width and height passed to convertBitmapRGBA8ToUIImage is in actual pixels, not UIKit 'points'. I.e., on iPad 1, it would be 1024, 768. On iPad 3, it's 2048, 1536.

The raw data buffer is RGBA data read from glReadPixels and flipped manually before passing to tweetMessage().

```
- (UIImage *) convertBitmapRGBA8ToUIImage:(unsigned char *) buffer
                                withWidth:(int) width
                               withHeight:(int) height {

    CGDataProviderRef ref = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer, width * height * 4, NULL);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, width * 4, colorspace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast, ref, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    float scale = 1.0f;
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
    {
        scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(width/scale, height/scale), NO, scale);
    CGContextRef cgcontext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetBlendMode(cgcontext, kCGBlendModeCopy);

    // Image needs to be flipped BACK for CG
    CGContextTranslateCTM(cgcontext, 0, height/scale);
    CGContextScaleCTM(cgcontext, 1, -1);
    CGContextDrawImage(cgcontext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width/scale, height/scale), iref);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CFRelease(ref);
    CFRelease(colorspace);
    CGImageRelease(iref);

    return image;
}

- (void)tweetMessage:(const char *)message withURL:(const char *)url withImage:(unsigned char*)rawRGBAImage withWidth:(unsigned int)imageWidth withHeight:(unsigned int)imageHeight
{
    UIImage *tweetImage = nil;
    if (rawRGBAImage != nil)
    {
        // Convert raw data to UIImage
        tweetImage = [self convertBitmapRGBA8ToUIImage:rawRGBAImage withWidth:imageWidth withHeight:imageHeight];
    }
}
```

Comment: So did you try it with no translate and no scaling? What I suggest is trying to get it to work in a minimal way (scale 1 etc), then try retina scaling, then try your CGContextTranslateCTM and CGContextScaleCTM. Staring from something that works and extended it a step at a time is going to solve the problem for you.

Comment: so the issue is that it's not working on retina screens - where your scale != 1. a) comment out where you change scale and see what happens. b) looking at the flipping code, i wonder if you're just drawing offscreen. as in moving the context halfway down, flipping it, and drawing the offscreen half.